# The system cannot find the file specified in ml.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2019, ml.net

I try add ml.net model . I directory is correct. while evaluate stage I got this error. Kindly solve this problem. tell me best way to understand ml.net

```
(Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.Utils.Logger.Info)
2023-07-12 15:46:55.6486 DEBUG The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.ML.CodeGenerator.Utilities.Utils.CreateSolutionFile(String solutionFile, String outputPath)
   at Microsoft.ML.CodeGenerator.CSharp.CodeGenerator.GenerateOutput()
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLEngine.<StartTrainingAsync>d__30.MoveNext() in /_/src/Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLService/AutoMLEngineService/AutoMLEngine.cs:line 183 (Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.Utils.Logger.Debug)
2023-07-12 15:47:04.8472 DEBUG Open Log FileC:\Users\Fantasy-Pc\AppData\Local\Temp\MLVSTools\logs\b183c99f-f026-442a-9660-12409131c92f.txt (Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.Utils.Logger.Debug)
2023-07-12 16:20:46.8733 DEBUG Open Log FileC:\Users\Fantasy-Pc\AppData\Local\Temp\MLVSTools\logs\b183c99f-f026-442a-9660-12409131c92f.txt (Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.Utils.Logger.Debug)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank uu for the response . Answer is My Framework of net not support for version of ml package . I try Different version it's work :)